# Toast notifications do not work in windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-8, toast

I have some toast notifications with alarm scenario. I used the following toast schema, but when notification is raised, there are no buttons(snooze or dismiss).
Here is my xml content. So why cant i use this toast commands?

```
    var contentString = "<toast duration=\"long\">\n" +
                               "<visual>\n" +
                               "<binding template=\"ToastText02\">\n" +
                               "<text id=\"1\">" + alarmTitle + "</text>\n" +
                               "<text id=\"2\">" + alarmNote + "</text>\n" +
                               "</binding>\n" +
                               "</visual>\n" +
                               "<commands scenario=\"alarm\">\n" +
                               "<command id=\"snooze\"/>\n" +
                               "<command id=\"dismiss\"/>\n" +
                               "</commands>\n" +
                               "<audio src=\"ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Alarm2\"\n" +
                               "loop=\"true\"/>\n" +
                               "</toast>\n";
```

Comment: Have you set "Toast Enabled" in your app manifest?

Comment: @BenjaminDiele Yes, standard toasts are working, but without commands and buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is normal, Windows Phone 8 RT does not have the all features of Windows Store Apps.

[There is a link on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn642486%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) that says what is not available on WinRT apps.

One of the entries is [Alarms and reminders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202946%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), so sadly you will not be able to use alarms on WP8.1.